# Does this "Clang vs GCC" question deserve to be Historically Locked?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, historical-lock

This question: [Clang vs GCC - which produces faster binaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3187414/10871073), which was asked 11½ years ago, was (rightly) closed as opinion-based ("Seeking recommendations …" may also be appropriate) but it does appear to be both popular and useful (136k views, +272 score and over 100 users have bookmarked it). It also has some great answers.

In the ~5 years since its closure, it has attracted 4 delete votes – 6 more such would remove it from general view, which I don't think is appropriate. It is currently in the [Reopen Votes Review Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/30680598) where, ironically, it may attract more delete votes.

Should this question be historically locked, to prevent possible deletion by over-zealous 'curators'? (I believe that it *should* be locked but others may disagree.)

Comment: One more delete vote has appeared since I posted this question. Isn't there a "rule" that posts actively under discussion here shouldn't be delete-voted?

Comment: Perhaps an unwritten rule?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I think a moderator *did* write it down somewhere, but it was deleted. :)

Comment: But I agree with this rule, written or unwritten

Comment: Related: "[What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126587/271271)"

Comment: IMO it shouldn't even be locked, let alone deleted. The question is **not** opinion-based.

Comment: @tdy: It's not *directly* opinion-based, but choice of which thing to benchmark could sort of count as an opinion.  (Or if one doesn't realize that that matters tremendously, then a failure of benchmark methodology, especially for an answer that benchmarked code with only one or a couple hot loops where the program spends the majority of time.)

Comment: What further answers would benefit the question (for those who don't think it should be locked or closed)? I know nothing about the subject, but it seems that people see a popular question and immediately jump on the "we must keep this question around forever and ever in an open state as testament to all that is holy and good in this world" bandwagon, as opposed to looking at the question objectively and deciding what value the question brings.

Comment: @PeterCordes I see where you're coming from. At the same time, could we imagine an answer that includes all possible benchmarks on all possible architectures for all possible programs and takes a median/average approach for which the binary produced is fastest (or something like that)? I can't answer that question, but can we _imagine_ an answer like this (maybe we can't, halting problem-esque? Still, sounds like a potential non-opinion answer even if Turing swats us down)? Is it really an opinion? I'm not sure. Can we just leave the question open ffs, does it hurt anything leaving it open?

Comment: @MattMessersmith: I'm undecided on whether it should be left open.  It could turn into a mess if too many answers go in different directions with different benchmarks, of different versions of GCC and clang.  OTOH, there might be more value we could get out of it than just having a historical snapshot of whatever benchmark ideas people had back then / until now.  Overall I'm mostly in favour of leaving it open; the official rules would let us close it, but we can choose not to.  It's in the gray area, IMO.

Comment: The problem with the question is not that it's opinion-based but that it's very broad and might change depending on version, arch, etc. But if an answer shows the question does have a broadly applicable answer, then maybe it's ok as not too broad to be answerable.

Comment: @Peter (and others) I'm not advocating, one way or the other, if it should stay closed or reopened. I just feel - strongly - that it shouldn't be deleted. I saw it in the Reopen Queue and skipped ... but also noticed  the accumulation of  delete votes, so I raised a discussion.

Comment: **100% agreed it shouldn't be deleted**.  IDK if setting it as a "favourite" will help notice if it does get deleted, so I can vote to undelete. Discussion in comments was getting into the details of locked vs closed but unlocked vs. fully open, which is also relevant.  If we leave open, perhaps a note at the top or bottom of the question linking to meta discussion about how it's not a model question for future askers, etc. (And perhaps mentioning a non-deletion consensus). I haven't yet seen any argument here in favour of deletion; would be curious to see one of the voters argue their case.

Comment: Don't delete. Jeez. Clearly a lot of work there. Can we solve real problems?

Comment: The question was asking which one is better when it was closed then it was edited to ask which one is faster. In its current state I think there is no need to either close or lock it.

Comment: @ayhan Well, since it has been reopened, the 'threat' of deletion has receded (but, should it be closed again, those 6 delete votes will still be there). Unfortunately, I don't think there is a mechanism that can lock a post against deletion but not against close/reopen.

Comment: Yeah but that's why more delete votes are required to delete these questions. A historical lock would bring more restrictions in addition to protection against deletion and I don't think that's justified here.

Comment: @ayhan Fair comment. Maybe a lock isn't an *ideal* option but I really don't like to see such posts deleted. There are some excellent answers and, as stated in the [10k Privileges Welcome Page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools): *We don't like to lose great answers!*

Comment: The last edit to the question adds "could you point me to some pre-existing resources", which makes it look more off-topic than before. Perhaps a better edit would be less likely to attract close-votes.

Comment: @AdrianMole No, those delete-votes won't still be there if it's closed again. Reopening a question clears any existing active delete-votes (i.e. delete-votes which have not yet caused the question to be deleted).

Comment: @Makyen OK - I didn't know that ... TIL! :-) (However, reopening a deleted question - which *is* possible - doesn't undelete it.)

Comment: @Makyen Are those delete votes still counted though? i.e. can a user vote to delete it again, given that the original delete vote didn't actually complete? Ok, it [appears not](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34349). That doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: The term "over-zealous 'curators'" is rather disrespectful. SO strives for high quality and it is done by volunteer moderation. It's natural that for some questions there will be some disagreement in judgement. I don't think it's justified to use such tone towards people who simply have a different opinion on the quality/fitness of a question (disclaimer: I haven't seen this question ever, nor have I voted on it).

Comment: @cigien No, a user who's delete-vote was cleared as a result of the question being reopened can not vote to delete the question again. There [have been some proposals that this behavior be changed](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34349/323585) (status-deferred) . [My personal opinion](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34349/voting-to-delete-a-question-after-it-has-been-reopened-and-reclosed#comment159449_34349) is that if your vote didn't participate in the post changing state, then you should be able to recast your vote, with some restrictions as to how rapidly you can recast your vote.

Comment: btw looking at it now, I agree it should be deleted. The fact that there is "a lot of work there" doesn't change anything, because we don't judge questions solely by the fact that someone has put a lot of work in the answer.  Not only it is too broad, but it's guaranteed to get out of date every time a new version of either compiler is released. Updating this ad infinitum is pointless.

Comment: Given the incoming new 8,000 questions per day (a total of [22,068,765 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)), most of them low-quality or beginner-level duplicates (or both), I don't see any harm in keeping a few of these questions around that *clearly* have some value (*"[it is not an exact science](https://www.dontpanicgeocast.com/)"*).

Comment: [Case in point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70522174/is-python-better-or-c-for-which-feature-do-you-use-it).

Comment: Temporarily locked since Meta is thrashing it open and closed

Comment: please focus on that rubbish 0 value questions swamping in on a daily base. But on the other hand leave that historical content for future readers. Close it, if necessary. Lock it, if necessary, but please don't delete it to the eyes of <10k ers. Thank you all involved!

Comment: I'm going to cast my delete vote just to take it out of its misery.

Comment: @Vickel why do you care about it? Yes we have rubbish, but this is also rubbish. So all rubbish must be thrown out. Old, new whatever.

Comment: @Braiam because I think "rubbish" from the past (highly upvoted and visited questions, with a lot of upvoted answers) should stay: mainly to serve as an example for the future, kind of a sign-post where similar new rubbish can be easily duplicated to, as well as it might be an interesting read for developers checking on how certain issues were treated (answered) in the past and get to their own conclusions.

Comment: I think @Vickel that for someone like you, that have been around, you know that high upvotes and views usually means "low hanging fruit", heck, the [best programming joke](https://stackoverflow.com/q/234075) blows this question away. So, review those arguments since they are DOA.

Comment: @BartoszKP I can easily say there are over-zealous curators here. I had question A closed as duplicate of question B, where the first paragraph of question A links to question B and discusses how they differ and how answers for B don't answer A. There are definitely people with close-vote powers who use them on the review queue without reading past the title.

Comment: I still think this question can yield good, mostly objective answers. And the main reason for controversy is that for many people this objective difference is anything but - it's their personal religious belief in a holy war, and any infidel challenging their belief is automatically subjective and wrong. I might agree with justification of "too broad" as an analysis of domains where one shines and the other doesn't could be a book's worth. But a matter of opinion? Only to those who conflate "inconvenient facts" and opinion.

Comment: @BartoszKP never mind one of the delete votes came with a comment, where the commenter was literally dissatisfied with the scope, that the question was about the resulting binaries and not factors like compilation time... literally "delete it because it's not asking the questions I want answered".

Comment: @ayhan: No, it didn't. The title had "better" because that makes for an easy, simple title. But the body asked for two very objective factors: execution speed and memory footprint. Since many curators don't read past the title before voting, I removed the memory footprint factor.

Comment: One more issue: it's only subjective when it's a close call. At the time of asking the question, if I asked "which has faster compile times" the answer would be unambiguous, unchallenged "Clang". The difference was so large there were no test cases where GCC would compile faster. That was also what triggered this question: does Clang manage to outperform GCC on speed so much by doing the bare minimum mechanical translation while GCC optimizes the binary? Or were its authors so brilliant they achieved such compile time gains without compromising the end result quality?

Comment: @Machavity: I'll cast my vote for historical lock because the alternatives are worse. Answers going to age out rather rapidly, keeping it up to date isn't happening, and it's really broad overall. I would have thrown a closed - too broad on it at the time but with a 200+ answer on a 200+ question that's a bad idea now.

Comment: @SF. "this question can yield good, mostly objective answers" it hasn't in all years it has been up, what makes you think it will in the future?

Comment: @Braiam At least 287 users who upvoted the top answers disagree with you. But you may have support of its 7 downvoters.

Comment: @SF Yes, there are people who make mistakes. Doesn't justify name-calling still IMO :) And the fact what some close-voter said and you think what they were thinking - irrelevant.

Comment: I don't think this question can be categorized as being "too broad", as some people are suggesting. It clearly asks which compiler produces _faster binaries_. No more, no less. Neither is it "opinion based", because if a compiled binary performs different on different devices, it isn't a matter of "opinion", it's more like the question "depends too much on user's hardware", if there's a question category like that

Comment: @BartoszKP I found some users treat votes to close as a kind of super-downvotes. Instead of need for a couple hundred downvotes to sink a question with inconvenient answers that say bad things about their dearest baby, all they need is 5 votes to close and 10 votes to delete, and all the slander against their dearest piece of software is gone!

Comment: @SF. no, 287 users just agree with the results. People have been saying since a quite while that Clang is faster that GCC, the reality of it [is more nuanced](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=aocc32-clang-gcc&num=1) and depends on many factors: from the what to measure, how to measure, etc. all of them very broad in nature and people will disagree which are the correct sets.

Comment: @Braiam So, you *know* why those 287 people upvoted, do you? Maybe you're wrong and they (or some of them) did so because they found the Q/A well-presented, well-researched and useful?

Comment: @SF Sorry, but I don't even know where to start, so I'll pass :) Cheers!

Comment: No, I know that their vote is meaningless and therefore irrelevant, because how I can't know why they voted, you can't either and so SF., Since everyone is _wrong_ the votes should be ignored and evaluate the posts at face value in which case, doesn't make any case for non-deletion.

Comment: Looking at [the edit history of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/414983/17242583), I _this_ question deserves to be historically locked! :P

Comment: SF. 3 close votes are needed to close a Q nowadays, not 5 anymore.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) from @Makyen's comment on the question, this is the criteria of a post whether it is appropriate for historical lock.

> When is it appropriate to lock a question for historical reasons?
> Questions can be historically locked when:
>
> 1. The post does not meet the current guidelines for a good, on-topic
>    question, and
> 2. The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature, and
> 3. There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the
>    post, and
> 4. The post is contentious; e.g., it has been closed and reopened at
>    least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once.

So, let's check it one-by-one.

> 1. The post does not meet the current guidelines for a good, on-topic
>    question, and

The post here does not meet the current guidelines because it is closed as opinion-based question.

> 2. The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature, and

As I am not a native English speaker, I don't know much about the meaning of the word "stellar" here, so I [googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=stellar%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_enTH864TH864&oq=stellar%20meaning&aqs=chrome.0.0i512l10.2608j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

[image: Stellar Meaning]

I will give it the "exceptionally good; outstanding" meaning because I think it is the most appropriate one here.

Therefore, the post in question must be exceptionally good and/or outstanding.

I would say, for me, it is questionable. Really subjective -- depends on who see/ don't see the values from the question.

> 3. There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the
>    post, and

"Large" number of views, upvotes and inbound links. Let's look at the number. As of 29/12/2021, it has 137k views, 273 upvotes, and 102 inbound links including bookmarks/favorites.

Since no one defines how much is it for "large" in here, so it is difficult to say whether those numbers satisfy the criteria.

> 4. The post is contentious; e.g., it has been closed and reopened at
>    least once, or deleted and undeleted at least once.

By looking at the history of the question's activities and as @Adrian Mole
's comment, the question was closed and has now been reopened, which makes it contentious.

**Summary**

It is debatable for the question to be historically locked because some criteria are clearly satisfied but some are questionable.

Comment: A lengthy conversation about counting links and POV was [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240609/discussion-on-answer-by-holydragon-does-this-clang-vs-gcc-question-deserve-to).

Answer (score 7):

No, the question doesn't really deserve a historical lock.

First, we have to ask whether the question should even be closed, and the answer is yes, definitely. The question is way too broad, and the only reasonable answer is "it depends on many many factors" (which all 7 answers admit). The question is not very different from "Is Java or Python faster?", say, which I expect most users would think is not a question that should stay open.

Now we can ask whether a historical lock is appropriate. These locks are for posts that are off-topic (which this one definitely is), but are nonetheless very useful. Having read through the answers, I can't really find any useful information in there. There are a couple of answers that describe in depth the results of bench-marking both compilers on specific projects, but that doesn't generalize in any way (as the answers clearly state). The results are also rather out of date (the most recent version of GCC in the answers is 5.2, which is quite old).

Now, if there existed an answer that demonstrated *how* to go about performing comparisons between both compilers, *that* would be useful. None of the answers show how to do that though, so as it stands, the answers are just anecdotal.

To address some of the arguments made in this meta question:

- Yes, the question has lots of views, but for a decade old question with an extremely click-baity title like "Is GCC or Clang faster?", that's to be expected. As a daily user of both these compilers, I'm almost guaranteed to click on a title like that.
- Yes, the question has lots of upvotes, but again that's to be expected for similar reasons as mentioned in the above bullet point. Also, clearly a lot of effort went into writing the top scoring answer, and an upvote is a good way to reward that. However, demonstration of effort is irrelevant on Stack Overflow when it comes to determining if a post should be open/closed/deleted; it only matters whether the post is useful.
- Yes, the question has been bookmarked by a lot of users. I don't actually know the reasons for that. Personally, I would bookmark a question like that to use it with my gold tag badge as a duplicate target for questions like [What are the key differences among the gcc, mingw, clang compilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70486524) so as to save wasting 2 close votes on a "POB", or "Needs more focus" reason (which are also valid reasons). Maybe some of the bookmarks are for that, I couldn't say.

---

To summarize, I'm not advocating strongly for deletion; the question (while it was closed), was not causing any harm. I would have just let it be, and not shed any tears if it happened to be deleted. However, bringing it up on meta makes that pretty much a non-option. Within a couple of days, the question will either be deleted, or historically locked, and if I *have* to choose between those options, I'm going for deletion.

Note: In the future, if you think a question deserves a historical lock, you should flag it for moderator attention first, and if the decision doesn't go the way you want it to, *then* raise the issue on meta. This avoids unnecessary drama, and in particular, avoids blatantly off-topic questions from being reopened by users who may be doing so as an "anti-delete" vote. (This "anti-delete" is now particularly effective, since it turns out none of the 5 delete voters can vote to delete the question again, now that the reopening has voided their delete votes.)

Comment: "In the future, if you think a question deserves a historical lock, you should flag it for moderator attention first, and if the decision doesn't go the way you want it to, then raise the issue on meta"  I really hate moderators locking questions. I still have yet to see a question that actually benefit from this, it's usually done out of annoyance with some feature (people flagging a post because zalgo) or with a very unproductive hoarding mentality.

Answer (score 6):

This question sadly is a loaded question, it asks for benchmarks for two very complex enormous applications which has similar objective: convert code to binary. This question while you can measure performance between two applications, at the end you are doing some kind of micro-benchmarking. What if your program relies heavily on one feature that the compiler is poorly optimized, or well optimized; difference between versions; difference between flags; which processor was used; how much memory; <insert here any other potential variable>.

Those kind of questions are closed as too broad, there's too many things that we have to consider to have an authoritative answer.

This obviously doesn't answer the question: should this question be historically locked? No, it should not. It has many issues and it isn't particularly high quality. [The information is obsolete (Phoronix article about GCC vs Clang on Intel i9 11900k: shows just .1% difference between both in most benchmarks)](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=11900k-gcc11-clang12&num=1) at best and misleading at worst. Since that was the whole point of the question, there isn't any redeemable quality that can save this question from deletion.

Comment: Oh, look at this, another more recent benchmark but with AMD's https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=aocc32-clang-gcc&num=1 :)

Comment: The question was being updated and kept up to date with newest changes for years while it was still open.

Comment: *Obsolete* and/or *misleading*? Should we then burn all 1st editions when a 2nd edition is published? No, of course not! At the very least, this question has well-researched information that could serve as good basis for any future, related posts. I agree that it is *now* off-topic, but maybe not at the time of posting

Comment: @AdrianMole people looking for this is looking for up to date information. We aren't providing that, and there's several resources that provide it. You don't need to burn the books, just store them in a box and forget about it.

Comment: Putting the books in a box would be the equivalent of closing and locking the question. Deleting the question would be like burning the books. The question (and the books) may contain information that is of historical value.

Comment: Good point about up to date phoronix benchmarks; the question or the top answer should be edited to have a section linking those, and that future readers should check there for up-to-date test results.  Their methodology and set of programs benchmarked is likely a more reasonable cross-section than whatever some one-off test from someone maintaining an SO answer would do.

Comment: @PeterCordes how about we remove our version and just let people find Phoronix articles. Or better yet, let them find out about openbenchmarking.org. We don't need to have actual benchmarks on the site. How to benchmark is ok, how to improve my code to fare better in a specific benchmark is ok, finding what is slow in my code is also ok. There are many interesting questions around benchmarks that are timeless and need low maintenance, unlike actual benchmarks where you need to specify so many variables, lets steer clear of that mess.